# Update a column of a table with data from another table if columns match PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

[image]I want to add multiple values to a column if the value in the column matches another value in a column from another table.

e.g.

table1 
column1.1 
column1.2

table2 
column2.1
column2.2

If column2.2 = column1.1 then update column1.2 with column 2.1

Should be able to write multiple values into column 2.1

Here is what I had but it's not working.

SET    column1.2 = table2.column2.1
FROM   table2
WHERE  table1.column1.1 = table2.column2.2

Comment: Sample data and desire results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, added picture to see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want an `update` from another table.  The syntax looks like this:

```
update table1
    set column1 = table2.column1 
    from table2 
    where table1.column2 = table2.column2;
```

I can't follow the dance of column names in your question, but this is the structure of updating columns in one table from another table.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it -

```
update table1
    set column1.2 = table1.column1.2 || ' ' || table2.column2.1 
    from table2 
    where table1.column1.1 = table2.column2.2;
```